# Reducer returning NAN from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, undefined, nan

#### Problem

I have an array like so:

```
let oddsArray = [undefined, undefined, 5, 5]
```

And a reducer function:

```
const reducer = (accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue
```

When I call console.log I get this:

```
console.log(oddsArray.reduce(reducer, 1), 'oddsArray') /// NAN
```

Until the array no longer includes undefined:

```
[5, 5, 5, 5] /// 20
```

#### What I want to happen

I want to be able to add up all the numbers in the array, even if there are undefined values included in that array. So the initial array should have equaled:

```
let oddsArray = [undefined, undefined, 5, 5] // 10
```

How do I achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case you need a more generic approach, i.e, to sum only the numbers on an array with multiple type of elements, you can use [Number.isNaN()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN) to check if the current value of the `reducer` is a number or not:

```js
let oddsArray = [undefined, undefined, 5, 5, null, "hola", {"foo":"bar"}];
const reducer = (acc, currVal) => acc + (isNaN(currVal) ? 0 : currVal);
let res = oddsArray.reduce(reducer, 0);
console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can check for `undefined` value as follow: `currentValue || 0`

```js
let oddsArray = [undefined, undefined, 5, 5]
const reducer = oddsArray.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) =>
                      accumulator + (currentValue || 0), 0);
console.log(reducer);
```